# Значение фразы "inflating the widgets from a layout resource"

Tags: android

Как я понимаю, точного перевода на русский (в одно слово) у слова inflating нет, но используется оно в значении "создание `View`-элемента из содержимого `layout`-файла". Но что именно имеется в виду под следующей фразой?

> inflating the widgets from a layout resource

Это значит создание `View`-элемента из содержимого `layout`-файла исключительно с помощью метода `inflate` класса `LayoutInflater`, или же создание `View` c помощью `setContentView` тоже может быть описано этой фразой?

Comment: метод `setContentView()` вызывает инфлейт разметки, поэтому это фактически одно и то же. Сам процесс заключается в переводе из декларированного xml-языка разметки (текста с командами) в реальные объекты классов виджетов,. с которыми можно работать программно (вызывать методы и тд)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да оба эти варианты подразумевают `inflate`, то есть указывают Android системе отрендерить элемент, создав его в памяти.

Вы можете делать это неявно:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(){
         setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    }
}
```

Или явно использовать `LayoutInflater`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity .this); 
View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```